# Would Religiophobia be an accurate word for dislike of religion? If not, what word is?

Tags: single-word-requests

Other options I have seen include religiovilia and misallodoxia. Which of these would be the best/most correct for a dislike (not fear) of organized religion?  If none are, what word would be?

Comment: Do you want a word which disdains *theism*, or the metaphysical belief in the supernatural/divine, or one which only disdains organized communities which share those beliefs, and their structures and processes?

Comment: Not ...phobia for a "dislike". There could be rational, logical reasons for disliking something. A phobia is an irrational fear. [See Merriam Webster:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phobia) > **Phobia:** an exaggerated usually inexplicable and illogical fear of a particular object, class of objects, or situation.

Comment: Specifically organized religion, not spiritualism.

Comment: Cool. Can you edit at context in to your question, so other people can see the bigger picture?

Comment: Are you asking about a fear or a dislike? They are not the same.

Comment: ***Religiophobia***: is a fear or anxiety of religion, religious faith, religious people or religious organisations. http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/religiophobia. Probably ***irreligiousness*** comes close to what you appear to be looking for: indifference or hostility to religion: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/irreligious

Comment: I don;t know if it is an actual word but one of my philosophy teachers in the university used "anti-theism".

Comment: @gelolopez That's the word I thought of first too, and the one which prompted [my original comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251231/would-religiophobia-be-an-accurate-word-for-dislike-of-religion#comment547080_251231). *Antitheism* is typically used to describe someone who disagrees with the metaphysical conception of God or philosophies which embrace supernatural in general, not of organized religion. In other words, it attacks the theory, not simply the practice.

Comment: _Anti-_ is also the opposition to, not so much the dislike; _misotheism_  is the hate of God, and _anticlericalism_ is some opposition to the influence of the religious body politic in public affairs etc.; I think you also had the old adjective _misoclere_. Please note that [_freedom of religion_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_religion) is often a constitutionally protected right, just like expression; furthermore, the _International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights_ "protects theistic, non-theistic and atheistic beliefs...". "Dislike" is clearer than Greek/Latin imho. Thanks.

Comment: If Bill Maher can use [**Religulous**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHH2JItePlc), I think you can use (and be understood) "religiophobia" to denote a dislike or distain for organized religion.

Comment: Coffee -- note that phpbia means  **FEAR** of -- debilitating, crawl-under-the-bed fear ... like a panic-attack.  it has no connection whatsoever to "like" or not.  (You could well, and people do, have phobias about things they "like".)

Comment: [**Phobia**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/phobia)  *noun*: 1. a persistent, abnormal, and irrational fear of a specific thing or situation that compels one to avoid it, despite the awareness and reassurance that it is not dangerous. **2. a strong fear, dislike, or aversion**. see The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the distinctions between dislike and fear, **theophobia**,

> a fear of religion or gods

would seem to be useful. See, for more details, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophobia